# Можно ли в HTML для input задать шаблон вывода даты из БД

Tags: html, html5, css

Чтобы дата формата: `2014-02-01 12:22:00` выводилась в input как `01/02/2014` или более читабельней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразовать и поместить в `value`, если php, то:

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime(данные из бд))
```

Если нужна сама маска ввода, то можно задать в jQuery с [**Masked Input Plugin**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```